# how nodejs build webserever in frontend for fraework for react and angular

Tags: reactjs

I am new to web development and slowly understanding the web process . I want to know which how nodejs helps to build webserver in frontend ? for react applications npm start --> react-scripts start which runs application in localhost .here where exactly it create webserver and executes in localhost

Answer (score 0):

An application can have front end and back end. A ReactJs application can be the front end for example, and nodeJs can be the back end. The back end will offer the server and will communicate with the database.

So, concretely, you will have 2 different projects: client and server. The client project will be your ReactJS application. The server project will be the NodeJS server. You create each one separetly.

A server can be accessed by paths, for example

```
http://my-server.localhost/login

http://my-server.localhost/logout

http://my-server.localhost/users
```

So, a basic connection between client and server can be based on the url paths, so in your client project you can do:

```
window.location.href = "http://my-server.localhost/login";
```

to call the login service from the server. And then, in your server, you can redirect to a client's url path.

**BUT: the best way (for me) to establish connection between client and server is by using [socket](https://socket.io/).**

Socket is very simple, your client can emit requests to the server, and vice-versa:

```
socket.emit('hello', data);//where data can be any type of object, a string for example..
```

Similarly, the server can also emit requests to the client:

```
socket.emit('welcom', new_data);
```

Then, in the server and the client, you should hear for each request. Finally the code can be something like this:

Client side:

```
socket.emit('hello', data);// I will say 'hello' message (request) to the server..

socket.on('welcome', (data, callback) => {//I will hear to 'welcome' message(request) from the server..
console.log('server emited welcome with data =>', data);
});
```

Server side:

```
socket.on('hello', (data, callback) => {//I will hear to 'hello' message(request) from the client..
 console.log('client emited hello with data =>', data);
 socket.emit('welcome', ':)');//I will say(reply) 'welcome' to the client..
});
```

Hope this helps you to understand the concept.

Comment: i understood client and server architecture for backend serverside nodejs we are using http inbuilt server to create server and access further but how node js is creating for frontend projects which doesnt have backend .eg: after creacting react project itself the project boilerplate executes in localhost .here where node creating its server . here now there is no backend for simple example

Comment: why there is no backend for nodejs server ?!! There is! After specifying the port for your server (server.listen(8080);), when you go to localhost:8080, you can see your response (for example: res.end('hello!');), so in your code you can add the view into the response. Take a look on this: https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/2504541-ultra-fast-applications-using-node-js/2504972-creating-your-first-app-with-node-js

Comment: where i can see the create server method in application exactly .after creating react app it automatically opens in localhost .where i can find  server process internally in the react code structure